# Excel Search function order of precedence

Tags: excel

I am wondering does the search function support order of precedence? I need the search function to break execution once the first criteria is met.

**What my formula does**

Search Laptops!D2 for certain keywords, once found print the text to the left and cut out the rest.

**What I thought would happen**

Excel finds B820 in Laptops!D2 prints the text to the left and chops the rest

**What is actually happening**

Excel finds B820 and Windows in Laptops!D2, prints the text to the left of Windows and not B820

**My Formula**

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(Laptops!D2,LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(D1:D7,Laptops!D2))-1),"")
```

I have tried quoting my required Search parameters as follows

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(Laptops!D2,LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH({"B820","AMD","Pentium","Celeron","Windows","Intel","i3"},Laptops!D2))-1),"")
```

It gives the same result as when I reference them from D1:D7 which isn't too surprising.

Comment: I don't believe you've indicated in either of these questions what version of Excel, which would be helpful.

Comment: @Doug - I assume Excel 2010 - that was quoted in previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a point I made in your previous question - the formula was designed to cope with a **single** keyword in each cell - if there are multiple keywords what do you want to happen?

With the formula you quote you will get everything to the left of the **last** match in D1:D7, so if "Windows" and "B820" appear it will always get everything to the left of "Windows" if that's listed later in D1:D7. You can switch the order in D1:D7 to suit or use the other formula I suggested, i.e.

`=IFERROR(LEFT(Laptops!D2,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(D$1:D$7,Laptops!D2),1)-1),"")`

That version will always give you everything to the left of the **first** match in **Laptops!D2**

Does that help - if not can you give some examples where the formulas don't work and what you want to get.

Comment: So it does, I choose the other one